# Getting Table Data Using HttpGet

Tags: lua, lua-table, roblox

Hi I have a Lua table that i'm trying to get data from for a username or password Login

```
LoginDatabase = {
{"username"="Testing","password"="RingErs"}
{"username"="Hello","password"="nice"}
};
```

Thats the table but How could I make it so if I had a InputBox {textbox} with a button I could find the username and password that the person is logging in with.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided would cause a compilation error. If you want key-value pairs in a table you either have to do it like this:

```
t = {[value] = value}
-- eg:
t = {["eggs"] = 12, [5] = "red", [true] = function() end}
```

If you're using keys as strings with alphanumeric characters or the underscore symbol, you can simplify it to:

```
t = {string = value}
-- eg:
t = {red = "blue"}
```

And to answer your question, instead of making a list of tables that contain a username and password, just use username-password pairs:

```
LoginDatabase = {
    Testing = "RingErs",
    Hello = "nice"
}
```

This way you can easily get the password of a user with:

```
password = LoginDatabase[username]
-- eg:
password = LoginDatabase["Testing"]
-- or
password = LoginDatabase.Testing
```

Comment: Thank you I have referred to a different type of Whitelist now but this will be extremely useful in the future for more Scripts I make, thanks for the help.